# How to re-direct all not found routes to index.html using the Vertx router with Quarkus?

Tags: java, angular, kotlin, vert.x, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application which all packages an Angular SPA (bundled in the JAR). Quarkus provides the backend API routes for the frontend to consume. The Angular application build is copied to the `META-INF/resources` path in the target when the Quarkus application is built.

I am not using JAX-RS to register my routes. Instead I am directly registering them programmatically on the Vertx router inside the `fun onRouterReady(@Observes router: Router)` method.

I would like any route which is not recognised (either as a Vertx-registered route or as a static resource) to be re-directed to `index.html` so that my Angular application can load from all of its routes. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any way to do this.

I do not know how all the Quarkus routes function. I suspect that Quarkus itself is registering some routes using Servlets (or perhaps Vertx) because `index.html` is properly served on the root but my authentication root can prevent loading without authentication.

I have tried various things I have found through searches, such as:

```kotlin
router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create())
router.route().handler({ context: RoutingContext ->
    context.reroute("index.html)
})
```

where the idea is to create a static handler, followed by a catch-all which will re-write the request to `index.html` so that it is then caught by the static handler but this just results in an infinite loop (the static handler does not seem to be able to find `index.html`).

I have also tried adding a filter via JAX-RS (which I would like to avoid) but this does not work either.

There must be some way to set this up and I am sure that Quarkus code actually does somewhere, but I cannot find it. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like define an error page for a specific error-code or for all errors, but I do not have any experience with the tech you are using now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I will answer my own question here since I had particular requirements that were not met by the given answer.

Quarkus does indeed register its own handlers through a RestEasy standalone class (even though RestEasy is not included in my application). This includes the hot-reload routes (for dev mode), some security routes and static route handlers pointing to known static resources (presumably known at compile-time).

The static resources handler is given a low priority so is one of the last to be called. It seems to accept existing static resource paths and the route path (which it uses as `/index.html`).

The mistake I had made was not following the re-routing logic carefully enough. My code:

```kotlin
router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create())
router.route().handler({ context: RoutingContext ->
    context.reroute("index.html)
})
```

would intercept any paths which had not been matched to routes and re-route them (I am not looking to do a re-direct) to `/index.html`. However, re-routing starts the whole routing process over again, so I came back to my catch-all handler with the `/index.html` path and again tried to re-route it (because the static handler is only called much later).

The solution therefore is to ensure that I only re-route paths I have not already tried to re-route (and I can re-route to `/` instead of `/index.html`):

```kotlin
router.routeWithRegex("\\/.+").handler({ context: RoutingContext ->
    context.reroute("/")
})
```

and the Quarkus-added static resource handler will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe `Router` somewhere in application scoped class and set 404 error handler to redirect to `index.html`

```java
public void init(@Observes Router router) {
        router.errorHandler(404, routingContext -> {
            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(302).putHeader("Location", "/index.html").end();
        });
}
```

P.S using `routingContext.reroute("index.html");` will work as well, but it will keep path as it was(e.g you wrote `/testabc`, it will show your html file but path won't be `/index.html`). If you need exactly this then replace it with your option inside `errorHandler`