# router.errorHandler() not triggered in Quarkus

Tags: java, reactjs, resteasy, vert.x, quarkus

I'm building a Quarkus app with a React frontend. I'm very new to react and I'm currently trying to deploy my app. The problem is that once I build my react app and try to serve it with Quarkus on port 8080, fetching the "/" path works fine but entering "/contact" for example ends up on a 404 error page. I know there are some solutions to this problem already on the internet but every one of them that I found and tried did not work.
The problem seems to coming from react-router-dom that I use in the frontend app and which does not work well with Quarkus as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) shows. So i'm trying implement the "Catch-all" solution of the previous post.
The solution which seems to be the more promising to me would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197844/how-to-re-direct-all-not-found-routes-to-index-html-using-the-vertx-router-with) but on my side the errorHandler is never triggered when I get a 404 error :

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class RouterReactFix {

    public void init(@Observes Router router) {
        log.info("Initialized !"); // Triggered
        router.errorHandler(404, rc -> {
            log.info("404"); // Not triggered
            rc.reroute("/");
        });
        router.errorHandler(200, rc -> {
            log.info("200"); // Not triggered, but it isn't an error code so maybe not relevant
        });
        router.get("/my-route").handler(rc -> {log.info("TRIGGERED");}); // Triggered
    }
}
```

I could really use your help either to make this work with my react app or to find another working solution.
Thank your in advance.

Edit :

What I currently have as a "setup" :

In a "AppHandler.tsx" file :

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={'/'} component={HomePage} />
  <Route path={'/presentation'} component={PresentationPage} />
  <Route path={'/qanda'} component={QAndAPage} />
  <Route path={'/bots'} component={BotTabHandler} />
  <Route path={'/rules'} component={Rules} />
  <Route path={'/contact'} component={ContactPage} />
</Switch>
```

The usual way to navigate through my website is to click on buttons which are embedded in components like this one :

```js
  <Link to={buttonElement.page}> // where buttonElement.page has for example the value '/presentation'
```

Now if I click on the buttons ( components) of the page in the built version (the version served in a static way by the Quarkus server) all works fine, the url in the browser changes to (for example) localhost:port/presentation and my page is displayed correctly.
However, if on the same setup, still on the built version, I enter manually in my browser the url "localhost:port/presentation" I get a 404 not found error from Quarkus.
This error doesn't appear when the website is still served by React on port 3000 and other requests (server-related, such as DB calls) are proxied by React on port 8080 to be handled by Quarkus (I get no 404 error when I enter manually the URL into the browser search bar)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a kind of API along with serving static resources?

Comment: Yes totally @tmarwen, there are other endpoints which are served by Quarkus and those work fine, I'm trying to fix this error where if I enter a URL which is usually handled by the router-dom dependency of react when the app is served in a static way, it gives me a 404 not found error.

Comment: `entering` a URL is quite vague and may refer to different ways of accessing a resource. Would you update you post with a step-by-step description on how you are navigating your app with the routes (backend) scheme and the expectations? (the react-router config `<Route>`s configuration would be insightful as well)

Comment: I don't know if I need to notify you once edited but here we go @tmarwen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the *Vert.x* `router` configuration is not working, then I would assume there is a higher-level component which configuration is superseding the low-level *Vert.x* configuration.

Typically in these cases, I would guess you are using a *RESTful* resource provider implementation which typically would be *Resteasy* for *Quarkus*.

*Resteasy* provides other *JAX-RS* compliant means for handling exceptions mapped to REST resources where the **404** HTTP resource not found error would map to the `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException` exception.

To handle such an exception having it redirect to your web application root path, you would implement an `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` that may look as follows:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class CustomNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Handling " + e.getMessage());
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/")).build();
    }
}
```

*Note that the `@Priority(Priorities.USER)` annotation needs to be added to override the default Quarkus mapper*.

### EDIT

In case you would like to preserve the URL path so that the client side framework (React / React Router in your case) would display the appropriate content accordingly, you can stream the main `index.html` page at each unmatched request:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class MyNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        final InputStream indexIS = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources/index.html");
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(indexIS, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int c;
        try {
            while ((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) c);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/")).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(sb.toString(), MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirection is working great but the thing is the URI address gets totally replaced by the '/' location. I think the react-dom dependency is using the location in the URL to display the right component. Therefore you would need to serve the content found at the path "/" but with the location tag "/contact" (for example). I used something like `return Response.accepted().contentLocation(URI.create("/")).location(e.getResponse().getLocation()).build();`but it doesn't work and I couldn't find much more documentation on how to do such thing with quarkus.

Comment: I updated the answer with the adaptation needed to request the `index.html` page at each wrong request path.

Comment: Glad to be in help @Wollfie